# SQL Subquery returns multiple rows when grouping by

Tags: sql, union, addition, multiple-tables

I have two tables, both with columns:tstamp, weight, destination
I am trying to write a query to get the following columns from tables a and b into one table:
Count(*) from a as Acounts, 
Count(*) from b as Bcounts, 
Sum(Acounts, Bcounts) where destination=x
Where datepart(hh,tstamp) =y

I've been trying for several hours using unions, joins, and subqueries but can't seem to find the right solution. 
Column Bcounts is not showing up in my table as a column. Instead the results appear as a separate row under Acounts.

I'm not a SQL guy as I work mainly with PLCs. I'll post my code tomorrow.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PostgreSQL example.

## Assume these were your tables

```
create table a (tstamp timestamp, weight int, destination text);
create table b (tstamp timestamp, weight int, destination text);

insert into a values
('2020-01-01 10:00:00', 40, 'germany'), ('2019-01-01 10:00:00', 50, 'germany'), 
('2020-04-01 10:00:00', 10, 'germany'), ('2019-04-01 10:00:00', 20, 'germany'), 
('2020-01-01 11:00:00', 40, 'congo'), ('2019-01-01 11:00:00', 50, 'congo'), 
('2020-04-01 11:00:00', 10, 'congo'), ('2019-04-01 12:00:00', 20, 'congo');

insert into b values
('2020-01-01 10:00:00', 40, 'germany'), ('2019-01-01 10:00:00', 50, 'germany'), 
('2020-04-01 11:00:00', 10, 'congo'), ('2019-04-01 11:00:00', 20, 'congo');
```

## Query

We take the count and put a token about the source from table A. We combine it with the same kind of info from table b. Then, we use a `case` statement to selectively pull the count of a and b separately, and also in combination.

```
with combined as (
  select count(*) as counter, 'a' as source from a
  where destination = 'germany' and date_part('hour', tstamp) = 10

  union all

  select count(*) as counter, 'b' as source from b
  where destination = 'germany' and date_part('hour', tstamp) = 10
)
select
  sum(case when source = 'a' then counter else 0 end) as count_a,
  sum(case when source = 'b' then counter else 0 end) as count_b,
  sum(counter) as counter_a_b
from combined
```

## Result

> ```
> count_a | count_b | counter_a_b
> ------: | ------: | ----------:
>       4 |       2 |           6
> ```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=100b4d5d4c94789d2f2c05d79c464166

## SQL Server equivalent

```
with combined as (
  select count(*) as counter, 'a' as source from a
  where destination = 'germany' and datepart(hh, tstamp) = 10

  union all

  select count(*) as counter, 'b' as source from b
  where destination = 'germany' and datepart(hh, tstamp) = 10
)
select
  sum(case when source = 'a' then counter else 0 end) as count_a,
  sum(case when source = 'b' then counter else 0 end) as count_b,
  sum(counter) as counter_a_b
from combined
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ff9dd4f864792437cb27d143106db186

## MySQL equivalent

```
select
  sum(case when source = 'a' then counter else 0 end) as count_a,
  sum(case when source = 'b' then counter else 0 end) as count_b,
  sum(counter) as counter_a_b
from (
  select count(*) as counter, 'a' as source from a
  where destination = 'germany' and hour(tstamp) = 10

  union all

  select count(*) as counter, 'b' as source from b
  where destination = 'germany' and hour(tstamp) = 10
) t
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=660b0c84c0c1b04141d19cc8c6b6af6d

Comment: Here is my attempt.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=064c93d0410ea8426dc3f7956d968248
I am trying to get 8 columns, Hour, ACounts, BCounts, Gate1, Gate2, Gate3, Gate4, NoDest.
The Gate columns are added from tables a and b based on the timestamp.

Comment: @Caracicatriz where is Gate1, Gate2...etc.? You will have to provide more information  about your data before anyone can help.

Comment: Sorry,
I want to create column Gate1, when Destination = 1, Gate2, When Destination =2, etc. 
I am trying to create a report for a line that has two separate conveyors feeding into 5 Gates. 
The customer wants hourly counts broken down by conveyor, and destinations.
The Weights and destination are being recorded for each part that passes on the conveyor and then moved into tables a and b. Columns are as follows
Hour, A_Counts, B_Counts, Gate1, Gate2, Gate3, Gate4, NoDest

Comment: @Caracicatriz it seems like you might need to get a paid consultant to help out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get two separate tables to report Counts and Weights per line. The customer was fine with the data being on two tables. I actually learned quite a bit through all of my trial and error.

Comment: Very good @Caracicatriz. You must be proud of yourself. Good job. In this particular case, my answer was not a direct help to your question. When you ask your questions on StackOverflow, include examples - input and output you need. When you receive answers, select the one that closely matched your question and click on the tick mark by that answer to put closure to your question. You don't have to do that on my answer here because you solved the problem yourself. This is just for future reference.